# Authentication with System.Web.Http.ApiController + Postman - Not hitting breakpoints / not sure how this works

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-apicontroller

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) to implement authentication in an API, and Postman to test it.

I am having trouble making it work, in part because I am not really sure I understand how it is supposed to work.

If I remove the `[Authorize]` tag, the `Get()` method runs, I enter the breakpoint and I receive the reply that I expect. 
However if the `[Authorize]` is there, Postman replies with

> {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

Which is also what I would expect, however, I do not hit any breakpoints so I am not able to figure out where this authentication logic takes place

Where would I put the authentication logic, meaning where would I query the database to see if the Username/Password match to records.

This is the code I am working with

```
 public class X: ApiController
 {
    private void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
    { // breakpoint
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
    }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    { // breakpoint
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }

    public HttpSessionStateBase Session;

    [Authorize]
    public string Get()
    { // breakpoint
      ...
    }
```

Comment: `authorize` by default means the user should be authenticated, which means if you don't provide user credentials you are not able to reach the method at all

Comment: I did provide Username/Password through the Authentication-tab in postman, is there another step missing?

Comment: take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Elyas Esna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4437464/elyas-esna) who provided [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)

I made the following changes

**Added this** in the same file

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationHeaderValue = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
        var userNamePasswordString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationHeaderValue.Parameter));
    }
}
```

changed the `Register()` method

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorization());
}
```

and the attribute of `Get()`

```
[CustomAuthorization]
public string Get()
```